# Samsung gear app stuck on Update dialog and disconnect from my gear s3 frontier!

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have gear s3 frontier and I connect it to my galaxy s7 edge phone. It works great but for last 2 weeks when I open samsung gear app in my phone it show a dialog with this message:

> Notice
>
> A new version is available. Update the app to continue

[image: screenshot]

I can't ignore it and the only option I have is to press the Update button. After that it show a screen that say :

> Preparing to connect ...

[image: screenshot]

When the progress bar complete, the app close automatically and disconnect the watch.

I checked "google play" and "Galaxy Apps" but there is no update available for "Samsung Gear" app. and currently I can't connect my watch to my phone.

The solution I tried to fix this problem:

- I tried to uninstall Samsung Gear app and install it again with google play. It worked for few days but after that I have the above problem again
- I use the option of "Connect to new phone" on my watch. It factory reset the watch and connected my watch to phone. But again after a few days I have the above problem.

How can I solve this problem. I seriously offended because both of my phone and watch was Samsung flagships but they can't connect to each other. If I can't solve this problem I will throw away my phone and watch and I will buy an iphone x with apple watch.

Comment: did you get a fix.mine is doing same thing. I can only get app to open if I have no data on phone (disable wifi and Data).

Comment: @RichK It just fixed after a few days. I have no idea what was the problem.